# Chinese text-to-speech problems on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, text-to-speech, chinese-locale

We try to use build-in iOS text-to-speech tool for reading Chinese words in the app.
It's good in reading texts. But got problems reading separate words.

For example, we have character 还. It could be pronounced like "hái" with meaning "also, in addition"; and could be pronounced like "huàn" with meaning "to return".
In phrase 我还要还钱 (wǒ hái yào huàn qián) it pronounce 还 in both ways (correct).

In case of separate "还" iOS prefer to read it only like "hái". How to make it pronounce characters in the way we need it (if possible)?

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution you can cut required words from longer files and play them as audio instead of using TTS

Comment: Thanks. Will keep that in mind. But with such huge amount of words it would be perfect to deal without cutting audio.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, or moved on to other things, but if not: you can also feed the TTS plaintext pinyin and it will (usually) pronounce it correctly. For example, give it "hai2" or "huan4". It works pretty well except I have found it doesn't handle PY without an initial. so "e2" sounds like "eeee-arrr" (like it's trying to say "E-two".)